# How to build AWSiOSSDKv2?

Tags: xcode, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ios

Forgive me if this is a newbie question. I am trying to build the AWS iOS SDK and the build is failing. I am using XCode 10.1 Beta.

I have cloned the [AWS iOS SDK](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios) and have opened the [xcode project file](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/tree/master/AWSiOSSDKv2.xcodeproj). After opening the project, I attempted to clean, test, and build the project.

- Clean works
- Test fails
- Build fails.

[image: Build Errors]

## Build Error

### Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSiOSSDKv2-gfzlqdkwlorytgcialiewupaumtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSCognitoAuthUnitTests.xctest/Info.plist':

1. Target 'AWSCognitoAuthUnitTests' (project 'AWSiOSSDKv2') has copy command from '/Users/user/Documents/NewTouch/aws-sdk-ios/AWSCognitoAuthUnitTests/Info.plist' to '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSiOSSDKv2-gfzlqdkwlorytgcialiewupaumtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSCognitoAuthUnitTests.xctest/Info.plist'
2. Target 'AWSCognitoAuthUnitTests' (project 'AWSiOSSDKv2') has process command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSiOSSDKv2-gfzlqdkwlorytgcialiewupaumtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSCognitoAuthUnitTests.xctest/Info.plist'

### Multiple commands produce '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSiOSSDKv2-gfzlqdkwlorytgcialiewupaumtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSAllTestsHost.app/PlugIns/AWSCognitoAuthTests.xctest/Info.plist':

1. Target 'AWSCognitoAuthTests' (project 'AWSiOSSDKv2') has copy command from '/Users/user/Documents/NewTouch/aws-sdk-ios/AWSCognitoAuthTests/Info.plist' to '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSiOSSDKv2-gfzlqdkwlorytgcialiewupaumtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSAllTestsHost.app/PlugIns/AWSCognitoAuthTests.xctest/Info.plist'
2. Target 'AWSCognitoAuthTests' (project 'AWSiOSSDKv2') has process command with output '/Users/user/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AWSiOSSDKv2-gfzlqdkwlorytgcialiewupaumtw/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/AWSAllTestsHost.app/PlugIns/AWSCognitoAuthTests.xctest/Info.plist'

Comment: Please do not invalidate existing answers with edits/updates to the question. If you have a new question, ask it separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common reason:

Go remove those Info.plist files from your Build Phases > Copy Bundle Resources.
Whoever added them to the project accidentally checked a target checkbox.